# Cannot set up servant app using stack - "Could not find module ‘Servant’"

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to set up basic project using servant and stack loosely following official [servant tutorial](http://haskell-servant.github.io/tutorial/server.html) and [stack guide](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/GUIDE.md). As soon as I add `import Servant` stack build fails with:

```
Could not find module ‘Servant’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I've defined `servant` as a dependency of this module and stack noticed it as `stack dependencies` shows:

```
aeson 0.8.0.2
array 0.5.1.0
attoparsec 0.12.1.6
base 4.8.1.0
binary 0.7.5.0
blaze-builder 0.4.0.1
bytestring 0.10.6.0
bytestring-conversion 0.3.1
case-insensitive 1.2.0.4
containers 0.5.6.2
deepseq 1.4.1.1
dlist 0.7.1.2
double-conversion 2.0.1.0
ghc-prim 0.4.0.0
hashable 1.2.3.3
http-media 0.6.2
http-types 0.8.6
integer-gmp 1.0.0.0
mtl 2.2.1
network-uri 2.6.0.3
parsec 3.1.9
primitive 0.6
scientific 0.3.3.8
servant 0.4.4.2
string-conversions 0.4
syb 0.5.1
template-haskell 2.10.0.0
text 1.2.1.3
tforia-products 0.1.0.0
time 1.5.0.1
transformers 0.4.2.0
unordered-containers 0.2.5.1
utf8-string 1.0.1.1
vector 0.10.12.3
```

Code of module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module API
    ( ProductAPI
    , apiServer
    ) where

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics
import Servant

data Product = Product
  { id :: String
  , name :: String
  } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON Product

products :: [Product]
products =
  [ Product "id123" "shoes of some guy"
  , Product "id234" "hat of some gal"
  ]

type ProductAPI = "products" :> Get '[JSON] [Product]

apiServer :: Server UserAPI
apiServer = return products
```

Cabal definition of module:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     API
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , servant
                     , aeson
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

I have no idea where else I have to define that dependency so stack/cabal is able to pick it up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Servant` module comes from *servant-server*, as you can see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server) in the module list. The handy `Servant` module reexports everything from the *servant* package (which has all the types to describe web APIs) as well as the key things for running servant web apps.

Long story short: you need to add the *servant-server* package to your dependencies as well.